# Display output in a textfield after a button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I'm using a button to get the IP address. I want to display that IP address in the text field.
This is my front end code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMachIP" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox1"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="BtnGetIP" runat="server" CssClass="btn1" 
                    onclick="BtnGetIP_Click" Text="Get My IP" />
```

This is my backend code for getting the ip:

```
 protected void BtnGetIP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myHost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
    System.Net.IPHostEntry myIPs = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost);
    foreach (System.Net.IPAddress myIP in myIPs.AddressList)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(myIP.ToString());

    }
}
```

Instead of the message box, I want my IP to be displayed in the text area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please give a name to your textbox like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMachIP" NAME = "txtMachIPNAME" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox1"></asp:TextBox>
```

And in backend code

```
txtMachIPNAME.Text = myIP.ToString();
```

Comment: asp.net controls uses ID not name I think. it should be txtMachIP.Text = somevalue as string

Comment: although there is no need for the name. it's working perfect even without it. :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to store the values in a temporary string then output the final list of values to the textbox.

```
protected void BtnGetIP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    string myHost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName(); 
    System.Net.IPHostEntry myIPs = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost); 
    // Create a temporary string to store the items retrieved in the loop
string tempIPs = string.Empty;
    foreach (System.Net.IPAddress myIP in myIPs.AddressList) 
    { 
        tempIPs += myIP.ToString() + ", ";
    } 
    // Removes the redundant space and comma
    tempIPs = tempIPs.TrimEnd(' ', ',');
    // Print the values to the textbox
    txtMachIP.Text = tempIPs;
}
```